# selecting a number according to probability

Tags: probability-theory, iterated-function-system, chaos-game

[image]

Could anyone just tell me what does he, mean by at the point $2$, selecting a number according to the probabilities, $p(x_0)$? does he meant to chhose the largest one out of $p_i(x_0), i=1,2,\dots,N$?, let me write, $p_i$ are probability functions $X$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{N} p_i(x)=1\forall x\in X, \sigma_n=1,2,3,\dots, N $, $\omega_{\sigma_n}$
are mappings on $X$.
I am also not comfortable with the notation $\sigma_n$.

Thanks for helping. A little example would be fine too.

Comment: I would take it to mean randomly choose a number from $1$ to $N,$ where the probability of choosing $k$ is $p_k(x_0).$   He must mean to say choose $\sigma_1\in\{1,\dots,N\}$ since it doesn't make sense to apply an integer to $x_0.$

Comment: OKay Thanks, I was thinking that too. What do you think about the notation $\sigma_n$? Can it be better?

Comment: I don't see why you object to $\sigma_n$  What would you prefer?

Comment: what is $n$? he has not defined before, only $N$ I understand.

Comment: Okay, $\sigma_i$ then.  The subscript is a variable, it doesn't matter what you call it.  Still, what don't you like about $\sigma_i?$